# How do I append text to a label in google chart?

Tags: javascript, charts

I need to append text to the labels in a Google chart.

How can I append text to label to customize them? For example insted of '5' set 'Quantity: 5'

I've provided pictures and a working code snippet below!

**This is the way right now:**

> [image]

**This is what I want:**

> [image]

```js
var activos = [{
    "descripcion": "peri\u00f3dico",
    "riesgo": "5"
  },
  {
    "descripcion": "autom\u00e1ticas ",
    "riesgo": "2"
  },
  {
    "descripcion": " \tAusencia",
    "riesgo": "2"
  },
  {
    "descripcion": " \tAusencia de alto riesgo",
    "riesgo": "4"
  },
  {
    "descripcion": "negocio",
    "riesgo": "3"
  }
];

const loadchart = function() {
  let dataTbl = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTbl.addColumn('string', 'Descripcion');
  dataTbl.addColumn('number', 'Cantidad');

  activos.forEach(obj => {
    let data = [obj['descripcion'], parseInt(obj['riesgo'])];

    dataTbl.addRows([data]);
  });

  let chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

  chart.draw(dataTbl, {
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    title: 'Reporte de Activos'
  });
}

google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(loadchart);
```

```html
<script src='//www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
<div id='chart'></div>
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two images?

Comment: in first image the label doesn't  have an append text: '5'
in second image the label has an append text: 'Cantidad:5'